# Solution to the Exercise 1-22 (K&R) from the C answer book

Tags: c

My questions refer to the solution to the Exercise 1-22 from "The C programming language" (K&R).
There is an exercise.

> Write a program to "fold" long input lines into two or more shorter lines after the last non-blank character that occurs before the n-th column of input. Make sure your program does something intelligent with very long lines, and if there are no blanks or tabs before the specified column.

There is a solution from "The C answer book" (C. Tondo, S. Gimpel).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXCOL  10  /* maximum column of input           */
#define TABINC  8   /* tab increment size                */

char line[MAXCOL];  /* input line                        */

int exptab(int pos);
int findblnk(int pos);
int newpos(int pos);
void printl(int pos);

/* fold long input lines into two or more shorter lines  */
int main()
{
    int c, pos;
    
    pos = 0;                /* position in the line      */
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        line[pos] = c;      /* store current character   */
        if (c == '\t')      /* expand tab character      */
            pos = exptab(pos);
        else if (c == '\n') {
            printl(pos);    /* print current input line  */
            pos = 0;
        } else if (++pos >= MAXCOL) {
            pos = findblnk(pos);
            printl(pos);
            pos = newpos(pos);
        }
    }
}

/* printl: print line until pos column                   */
void printl(int pos)
{
    int i;
    
    for (i = 0; i < pos; ++i)
        putchar(line[i]);
    if (pos > 0)            /* any chars printed?        */
        putchar('\n');
}

/* exptab: expand tab into blanks                        */
int exptab(int pos)
{
    line[pos] = ' ';        /* tab is at least one blank */
    for (++pos; pos < MAXCOL && pos % TABINC != 0; ++pos)
        line[pos] = ' ';
    if (pos < MAXCOL)       /* room left in current line */
        return pos;
    else {                  /* current line is full      */
        printl(pos);
        return 0;           /* reset current position    */
    }
}

/* findblnk: find blank's position                       */
int findblnk(int pos)
{
    while (pos > 0 && line[pos] != ' ')
        --pos;
    if (pos == 0)           /* no blanks in the line?    */
        return MAXCOL;
    else                    /* at least one blank        */
        return pos+1;       /* position after the blank  */
}

/* newpos: rearrange line with new position              */
int newpos(int pos)
{
    int i, j;
    
    if (pos <= 0 || pos >= MAXCOL)
        return 0;           /* nothing to rearrange      */
    else {
        i = 0;
        for (j = pos; j < MAXCOL; ++j) {
            line[i] = line[j];
            ++i;
        }
        return i;           /* new position in line      */
    }   
}
```

Short explanation how the program works.

> `MAXCOL` is a symbolic constant. It indicates the n-th column of input. The integer variable `pos` points to the position within a line of text where the program currently is. The program folds input lines before the n-th column of input.
>
> The program expands tab characters, prints the current input when it finds a newline, and folds the input line when `pos` reaches `MAXCOL`.
>
> The function `findblnk` searches for a blank starting at the index `pos`. It returns the position after a blank or `MAXCOL` if a blank does not exist.
>
> `printl` prints the characters between position zero and `pos-1`.
>
> `newpos` rearranges a line, that is, it copies characters, starting at `pos`, to the beginning of the line, then returns the new value of `pos`.

My questions.

1. When `pos` equals `MAXCOL` the function `findblnk` is called. In the function first it's executed

```
while (pos > 0 && line[pos] != ' ')
    --pos;
```

Why there are no worries about bounds violation? As I understand it, array index varies from zero to `MAXCOL-1` and in `while` the value of `line[pos]` (`pos` == `MAXCOL`) is undefined.

2. In function `main`

`} else if (++pos >= MAXCOL) {`

why not just

`} else if (++pos == MAXCOL) {`

3. In function `newpos`

`if (pos <= 0 || pos >= MAXCOL)`

why not just

`if (pos == MAXCOL)`

To make the program extensible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Question 1:***
*Why there are no worries about bounds violation? As I understand it, array index = 0, 1, ..., MAXCOL-1 and the value of line[pos] (pos = MAXCOL) is undefined.*

Yes, there are concerns about bounds violation, but this note is accurate.  You need to make the distinction between the value used to *define* an array, such as `MAXCOL`, and the values used to *access* array elements: `0` through `(MAXCOL-1)`.  As you probably know, C uses zero based indexing for accessing elements of an array.  This is reflected in the above statement.  The phrase *pos == MAXCOL* is synonymous in this context with *count == MAXCOL*:

```
Array index ->  |0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|...|MAXCOL-1|

pos or count -> |1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|...|MAXCOL|
```

Or in other words, the zeroth *index* is the first *position*, and the first *index* is the second *position*, and so on.  Its just semantics.

***Question 2:***
When code uses a series of `if-then-else` constructs (or similar) as is done here, it is always a good idea to explicitly handle the case where the value being tested (i.e. `pos`) is advanced beyond the limit (i.e. `MAXCOL`) in one of the other cases.  If that were ever true,  then in this case `(++pos == MAXCOL)` could result in an infinite loop, where `(++pos >= MAXCOL)` would catch it.

***Question 3:***
`if (pos <= 0 || pos >= MAXCOL)`  is a condition that looks for the value being tested to be outside the bounds of the working region, while `if (pos == MAXCOL)` is simply checking that `pos` is out of bounds on the upper end.  Again, including a test for the lower bound is prudent, and would be considered by most a good programming practice.
Note that it might be acceptable to use `if (pos == MAXCOL)` iff it were not possible for the value `pos` to be negative.  i.e. perhaps it is defined as an `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

1) The test of `pos >0` is checking the boundary condition. The `while` loop is searching backwards, so one of the two conditions will always be met. Notice that since the loop is using a per-decrement `--pos`, the first value is `MAXCOL - 1`.

2 & 3) Using `>=` and `<=` instead of just `==` is just a good general practice just in case you somehow overflow the test condition. If you somehow "miss" the limit value when using `==` you will never exit the loop.